# FrameLayout cover ProgressBar in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In a `RelativeLayout`, I use `ProgressBar` and `FrameLayout`. I initialize `FrameLayout` with different fragments.

However I can't see `ProgressBar` because `FrameLayout` cover it. I don't want this.

I want to place the `ProgressBar` over the `FrameLayout`.(They should be overlapped but `ProgressBar` should be above).

How can I do that?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/mainProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How about writing ProgressBar after FrameLayout and switching Visibility in Java code?

Comment: @ysys Yes, problem is solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative layout shows view from bottom to top (means bottom child views will appear at top). To solve your problem you just need to place progressbar below framelayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/mainProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

</RelativeLayout>
```